# PHP/Java String to integer conversion

Tags: java, php

I am trying to convert two PHP functions into Java. The first function called `deAdjustId()` converts a `String` to an `Integer` like this:

**input:** ABCD

**deAdjustId() produces**: 1094861636

The PHP code of deAdjustId():

```
function deAdjustId($data)
{
    if (strlen($data) < 4) {
        $data = "\x00".$data;
    }
    $data = strrev($data);
    $data = unpack('L', $data);
    return $data[1];
}
```

After that another function called `adjustId` can convert the result from `deAdjustId()` back to the given input like this:

**adjustId() returns:** ABCD

The PHP code of adjustId():

```
function adjustId($id)
{
    $data = strrev(pack('L', $id));
    $data = bin2hex(ltrim($data));
    while (strlen($data) < 6) {
        $data = '0'.$data;
    }
    return hex2bin($data);
}
```

Now my question is: Is there a similar way to do this in Java? Since Java doesn't support unsigned bytes, there must be another way to reproduce this result. I would be gratefull if somebody figures this out.

Some more tests done with different inputs:

```
Note that adjustId() calculates the value from deAdjustId()!
Test 1:
input: ABCD
deAdjustId(): 1094861636
adjustId(): ABCD

Test 2:
input: ABCDEFGHIJK
deAdjustId(): 1212762699
adjustId(): HIJK

Test 3:
input: Thequickbrownfox
deAdjustId(): 1852206968
adjustId(): nfox
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off the top of my head:

```
int deAdjustId(byte[] s)
{
    int r = 0;
    for (int i = s.length <= 4 ? 0 : s.length - 4; i < s.length; ++i) 
    {
        r = (r << 8) + ((int)s[i] & 255);
    }
    return r;
}

byte[] adjustId(int id)
{
    byte[] ba = new byte[4];
    for (i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
        char c = (char)(id & 255);
        if (c == 0) {
            byte[] ta = new byte[i];
            System.arrayCopy(ba, 4 - i, ta, 0, i);
            ba = ta;
            break;
        }
        ba[3 - i] = (byte)c;
        id = id >>> 8;
    }
    return ba;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you are awesome!

Comment: I changed it to use byte arrays, like in your edit, but I did it my own way, not bothering with the StringBuilder. I hope you don't mind.

Comment: one more point; adjustId() doesn't remove whitespace (see ltrim)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int deAdjustId(byte[] s) {
    int r = 0;
    for (int i = s.length <= 4 ? 0 : s.length - 4; i < s.length; ++i) {
        r = (r << 8) + ((int) s[i] & 255);
    }
    return r;
}

public static byte[] adjustId(int id) {
    byte[] ba = new byte[4];
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        char c = (char) (id & 255);
        if (c == 0) {
            System.arraycopy(ba, 4 - i, ba, 0, i);
            break;
        }
        ba[3 - i] = (byte) c;
        id = id >>> 8;
    }
    int k = 0;
    label:
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        switch (ba[j]) {
            case 0:
            case 9:
            case 10:
            case 11:
            case 13:
            case 32:
                k++;
                break;
            default:
                break label;
        }
    }
    byte[] output = new byte[ba.length - k];
    System.arraycopy(ba, k, output, 0, output.length);
    return output;
}
```